# XamarinForms : Binding the properties an ObservableCollection of custom class objects to a ListView in C# and XAML

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I've the following class :

```
public class NameObject
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool Suggested { get; set; }
        public bool Popular { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public short Personality { get; set; }
        public short Decade { get; set; }
        public string Origin { get; set; }
        public string Diminutives { get; set; }
        public string ShortMeaning { get; set; }
        public string LongMeaning { get; set; }
    }
```

I populate an ObservableCollection in the MainPage class with about 500 entries of this object. I've another class due to tab navigation that I need to populate a ListView in.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             x:Class="engME.YourFullNamesListPage">

    <ListView x:Name="FullNamesList" ItemsSource="">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextCell Text="{Binding ???}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>    
    </ListView>
</ContentPage>
```

My goal is to populate this ListView with every entry but only certain properties of the populated NameList. (name, gender, shortMeaning)

```
public partial class YourFullNamesListPage : ContentPage
    {

        public YourFullNamesListPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            FullNamesList.ItemsSource= MainPage.NameList;
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance for any help! I've been trying to figure this out for about 9 hours, but am still learning and have been unsuccessful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `Cell` will have the scope of one instance of your `NameObject` class.

You should be able to do this:

```
<ListView x:Name="FullNamesList" ItemsSource="">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextCell Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>    
</ListView>
```

If you want to show more info, you will need to find some way of doing that, in a `TextCell` you can also use `Details`. But you can also build your own design by using a `ViewCell`.

For instance, like this:

```
<ViewCell>
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        <Label Text="{Binding Gender}"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ViewCell>
```

Gathered from the comments, you have declared the `NameList` collection in the `ItemsSource` as a member, not a property. To be able to bind to a field, it has to be declared as a public property.

Change `public static ObservableCollection<NameObject> NameList = new ObservableCollection<NameObject>();`

into

`public static ObservableCollection<NameObject> NameList { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<NameObject>();`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but it didn't work.

The {Binding Name} has a warning stating "Cannot Resolve Symbol Name", and the list that appears on the app is empty.

Comment: It would be great to get a little more detail. "It didn't work" doesn't enable me to help you any further. What didn't work exactly? Did you receive any error? What happened? What did you change?

Comment: Sorry, I had hit enter before filling out the full response. I've edited it.

Comment: Alright :) Could you add a bit more detail to your question? What does your `MainPage.NameList` look like? And maybe remove the `ItemsSource=""` from your `ListView` as it doesn't have any use anyway.

Comment: Perhaps it is because :

public static ObservableCollection<NameObject> NameList = new ObservableCollection<NameObject>();

is declared in a different class than that which I am calling it from?

Comment: Nope, it's because it isn't a property. If you want to bind to it, it has to be a public property. Try this: `ObservableCollection<NameObject> NameList {get; set;} = new ObservableCollection<NameObject>(); `

Comment: That works! Editing the question with the solution. Thank you VERY much. I am going to go study up on this. 

One more question though, if I wanted to actually change what is displayed on the {Bind}, for example if Gender only has the string "F" but I would like it to display as "Female", and "M" to "Male" ow would I do that?

Furthermore, how would I show an image instead of what is in the entry. For example, if Suggested shows boolean TRUE, I would like to show a thumbs up.